# How to customize LogFormat for Apache Virtual Hosts?

Tags: apache, logging, logfiles, access-log

I really need some help with this. My server has multiple virtual hosts, each virtual host has its access log, I need to be able to customize the LogFormat for each virtual host exist on server. I have modified LogFormat in `httpd.conf` but it actually affects only the master access log and not the virtual hosts.

Here is my LogFormat:

```
<IfModule log_config_module>
LogFormat "%v:%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" combinedvhost
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" common

CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
CustomLog logs/access_log combinedvhost

<IfModule logio_module>
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" combinedio
</IfModule>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_log_config.c>
LogFormat "%v:%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" combinedvhost
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

CustomLog logs/access_log common
CustomLog logs/access_log combined
CustomLog logs/access_log combinedvhost

</IfModule>
```

The above LogFormat only affects the master access log which located at: `/usr/local/apache/logs/access_log` However, it does not affect any of the virtual hosts on server that have their access logs located at: `/home/username/access-logs/domain.com`

I'm not sure if I have something wrong in the LogFormat itself or I'm missing something. I've spent many hours trying to solve this problem but didn't find a solution. I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem.. And I just found out the file I read / edit is false. try search another config. in xampp.. the config in extra/httpd-vhost.conf

i found this

```
##<VirtualHost *:80>
##    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
##    DocumentRoot "C:/app/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
##    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
##    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
##    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
##    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>
```

erase the '#' ; Try edit inside the virtual host config.. I believe you edited in main site.. perhaps you can share the config that related to your vhost ..